# How to handle promise in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

here is my code to check a `doc` is there in the `collections`

```
this.shopCollection = this.afs.collection<Shop>('shops', ref => {
  return ref.where('fulladdress', '==', myString)
});
```

i don't know why i can't use `.then()` and `.catch()` with this method. When i pass a string to query and if no result found how i know?

I am using `angularfire2` version `^5.0.0-rc.1` with `angular ^4.2.4` and `firebase ^4.5.0`.

Please help.

Comment: Are you talking about the use of this method?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#collection

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, because i am using `angularfire2` they called it `AngularFirestoreCollection`. it looks both are same.

Comment: The returned AngularFirestoreCollection is not a promise.  Check out the docs to find out what you can do with it, you have a few options: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Comment: its an observable. instead of `.then()` you have `.subscribe()`

Comment: `.subscribe` works when query returns data. but if no data `.subscribe` not even running. [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) is what i am trying to achieve in `angularfire2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working with some changes

Here is my code

```
this.afs.collection<Shop>('shops').ref.where('fulladdress', '==', myString)
      .get()
      .then(res => {
        if(res.docs.length == 0){
          //no documents found
        }else{
          //you got some documents
          res.forEach(shop => {
            console.log(shop.id);
            console.log(shop.data());
          })
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('something went wrong '+ err)
      });
```

i am not sure this is the right way, works fine for me.